# Word Ladder without replacement in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, artificial-intelligence, breadth-first-search

I have question, where I need to implement ladder problem with different logic.

In each step, the player must either add one letter to the word
from the previous step, or take away one letter, and then rearrange the letters to make a new word.

croissant(-C) -> arsonist(-S) -> aroints(+E)->notaries(+B)->baritones(-S)->baritone

The new word should make sense from a wordList.txt which is dictionary of word.

[Dictionary](http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt)

My code look like this, 
where I have calculated first the number of character removed "remove_list" and added "add_list". Then I have stored that value in the list.

Then I read the file, and stored into the dictionary which the sorted pair.

Then I started removing and add into the start word and matched with dictionary.

But now challenge is, some word after deletion and addition doesn't match with the dictionary and it misses the goal.

In that case, it should backtrack to previous step and should add instead of subtracting.

I am looking for some sort of recursive function, which could help in this or complete new logic which I could help to achieve the output.

Sample of my code.

```
start = 'croissant'
goal =  'baritone'

list_start = map(list,start)
list_goal = map(list, goal)



remove_list = [x for x in list_start if x not in list_goal]

add_list = [x for x in list_goal if x not in list_start]



file = open('wordList.txt','r')
dict_words = {}
for word in file:
   strip_word = word.rstrip()
   dict_words[''.join(sorted(strip_word))]=strip_word
   file.close()
final_list = []


flag_remove = 0

for i in remove_list:
   sorted_removed_list = sorted(start.replace(''.join(map(str, i)),"",1))
   sorted_removed_string = ''.join(map(str, sorted_removed_list))

   if sorted_removed_string in dict_words.keys():
       print dict_words[sorted_removed_string]
       final_list.append(sorted_removed_string)
       flag_remove = 1
   start = sorted_removed_string
print final_list


flag_add = 0    
for i in add_list:
    first_character = ''.join(map(str,i))
    sorted_joined_list = sorted(''.join([first_character, final_list[-1]]))
    sorted_joined_string = ''.join(map(str, sorted_joined_list))

   if sorted_joined_string in dict_words.keys():
       print dict_words[sorted_joined_string]
       final_list.append(sorted_joined_string)
       flag_add = 1
sorted_removed_string = sorted_joined_string
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion-based backtracking isn't a good idea for search problem of this sort. It blindly goes downward in search tree, without exploiting the fact that words are almost never 10-12 distance away from each other, causing StackOverflow (or recursion limit exceeded in Python).

The solution here uses breadth-first search. It uses `mate(s)` as helper, which given a word `s`, finds all possible words we can travel to next. `mate` in turn uses a global dictionary `wdict`, pre-processed at the beginning of the program, which for a given word, finds all it's anagrams (i.e re-arrangement of letters).

```
from queue import Queue
words = set(''.join(s[:-1]) for s in open("wordsEn.txt"))
wdict = {}
for w in words:
    s = ''.join(sorted(w))
    if s in wdict: wdict[s].append(w)
    else: wdict[s] = [w]

def mate(s):
    global wdict
    ans = [''.join(s[:c]+s[c+1:]) for c in range(len(s))]
    for c in range(97,123): ans.append(s + chr(c))
    for m in ans: yield from wdict.get(''.join(sorted(m)),[])

def bfs(start,goal,depth=0):
    already = set([start])
    prev = {}
    q = Queue()
    q.put(start)
    while not q.empty():
        cur = q.get()
        if cur==goal:
            ans = []
            while cur: ans.append(cur);cur = prev.get(cur)
            return ans[::-1] #reverse the array
        for m in mate(cur):
            if m not in already:
                already.add(m)
                q.put(m)
                prev[m] = cur


print(bfs('croissant','baritone'))
```

which outputs: `['croissant', 'arsonist', 'rations', 'senorita', 'baritones', 'baritone']`